# How to display imageView and textView with inflater in SDK Android

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk, bitmap, layout-inflater

Hi when i run this i just got a black application. I link from an Activity to another Activity and do this:

CODE:

```
public static ImageView display; 
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_book, null);
    display = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageba);
    display.setImageBitmap(imageLoader.getBitmap(data.get(position)));
    text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textba);
    text.setText("Titel:");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageba"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="111dp"
            android:layout_weight="250.17"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/stub" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textba"
            android:layout_width="226dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="98.53"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dip" />
```

I want just to display the text and the Bitmap i got into a textView and into a imageView.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView` does all of the inflation magic for you.. Once you call `setContentView`, your view will be inflated and shown and you can retrieve your ImageView and TextView from there using `findViewById`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageba);
    display.setImageBitmap(imageLoader.getBitmap(data.get(position)));
    text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textba);
    text.setText("Titel:");
}
```

You were essentially inflating a second view and modifying the values of that but never actually displaying it.